# OSError Unable to create file (Unable to open .mat file, errno = 17, error message = 'File exists', flags = 15, o_flags = 502)

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook, h5py, anaconda3

I want to read this .mat file (https://www.kaggle.com/crawford/deepsat-sat6) and want to visualize/convert it as images in jpg.
Please refer the code and error below. Please help me to overcome the error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import h5py
from PIL import Image
filepath = 'D:\deepsat-sat6\sat-6-full.mat'
H5PY_DEFAULT_READONLY=1
f = h5py.File(filepath, 'r') #to open .mat file for reading
```

`OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = 'D:\deepsat-sat6\sat-6-full.mat', 
errno = 17, error message = 'File exists', flags = 15, o_flags = 502)`

Comment: Are you sure it's a `h5py` format, not an older MATLAB version?

Comment: It's a .mat file that I tried to open using python. But then I switched to MATLAB, and extract the required data.